# Unzipping from a folder of unknown name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip, unzip

I have a bunch of zip files, and I'm trying to make a bash script to automate the unzipping of certain files from it.
Things is, although I know the name of the file I want, I don't know the name of the folder it's in; it is one folder depth in

How can I extract these files, preferably discarding the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to unzip any given file at any depth and junk the folder paths on the way out:

```
unzip -j somezip.zip *somefile.txt
```

The -j junks any folder structure in the zip file and the asterisk gives a wildcard to match along any path.

Answer (score 1):

if you're in:

some_directory/

and the zip files are in any number of subdirectories, say:

some_directory/foo

```
find ./ -name myfile.zip -exec unzip {} -d /directory \;
```

Edit:  As for the second part, removing the directory that contained the zip file I assume?

```
find ./ -name myfile.zip -exec unzip {} -d /directory \; -exec echo rm -rf `dirname {}` \;
```

Notice the "echo."  That's a sanity check.  I always echo first when executing something destructive like rm -rf in a loop/iterative sequence like this.  Good luck!

Comment: Good call. I misread that he was asking for a certain subfolder inside a single zip, but you're right, he's asking for a certain zip file inside an unknown set of file systems subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `unzip somefile.zip "*/blah.txt"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to find the file that you need to unzip, and `xargs` to call unzip:

```
find /path/to/root/ -name 'zipname.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 unzip
```

`print0` enables the command to work with files or paths that have white space in them. `-0` is the option to `xargs` that makes it work with `print0`.